# How do this SQL queries cleaner, better, in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I have something like this:

```
SELECT cars.brand, cars.id FROM cars WHERE cars.brand = 4 LIMIT 1;
SELECT cars.brand, cars.id FROM cars WHERE cars.brand = 24 LIMIT 1;
SELECT cars.brand, cars.id FROM cars WHERE cars.brand = 29 LIMIT 1;
```

If will be more queries it will be very long.
How do this in the other way, in one line? But important is for me speed.
cars.brand = X AND LIMIT X is a variable so it maybe change.

Comment: So instead of n statements all with different brands and possibly even different limits you want only one statement? For what reason exactly?

Comment: Because 100 queries like this is not the best way I think

Comment: Because 100 single queries instead of one big query is too slow? Okay, I'll post an answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are worried about having to send so many queries one by one, so that would take a lot of time. You can make this one query instead:

```
SELECT cars.brand, cars.id FROM cars WHERE cars.brand = 4 LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT cars.brand, cars.id FROM cars WHERE cars.brand = 24 LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT cars.brand, cars.id FROM cars WHERE cars.brand = 29 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $ids = (4, 24, 29);
    $limit = 1;

foreach ($ids as $id){
    $query = "SELECT cars.brand, cars.id FROM cars WHERE cars.brand = $id LIMIT $limit";
    // perform query
    // store result
}
```

Comment: Thanks but if I want only LIMIT 2 for ID 24? What in this situation. IF $id =24 { LIMIT 2} ?... Only something like this but it is not good I think

Comment: I kind of feel you keep changing the question. If you want different limits with different ids you can extend the `$ids` array, give every id a limit instead of a separate `limit` variable and use it like `cars.brand = $id['id'] LIMIT $id['limit']`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cars.brand, cars.id FROM cars WHERE cars.brand IN(4, 24, 29) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: If I am understand your problem is correct then that is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1:**

```
SELECT cars.brand, cars.id 
       FROM cars 
       WHERE cars.brand = 4 OR cars.brand = 24 OR cars.brand = 29
       LIMIT 1;
```

**METHOD 2:**

```
SELECT cars.brand, cars.id 
      FROM cars 
      WHERE cars.brand IN(4, 24, 29)
      LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you do not seem to care which car id you return for each brand, just so long as there is only one for each brand then just use MAX or MIN to select an id grouping by brand:-

```
SELECT cars.brand, MAX(cars.id) AS id
FROM cars 
WHERE cars.brand IN(4, 24, 29) 
GROUP BY cars.brand;
```

This should be fast (assuming you have useful indexes).

If you want a different number of limited cars then you could sort them and use a variable to assign a number to each and then get rid of those with higher numbers than that number. For example to limit it to 3 of each:-

```
SELECT sub0.brand, sub0.id, @ctr := IF(@brand = sub0.brand, @ctr:=@ctr+1, 1) AS brand_ctr, @brand := sub0.brand
FROM
(
    SELECT cars.brand, cars.id
    FROM cars 
    WHERE cars.brand IN(4, 24, 29) 
    ORDER BY cars.brand
) sub0
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @ctr := 1, @brand := 0) sub1
HAVING brand_ctr <= 3
```

Depending on the number of brands this is not massively efficient, but it is very easy to create as dynamic SQL (you just need the ids in the IN clause to set up the SQL, rather than building lots of UNIONed statements).